# Google Sheets - FILTER function

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I work for an Amazon drop shipping business, and we have a spreadsheet of all the order information, including the order ID, quantity, cost, etc.

I have a different spreadsheet with the buyer information that I need to get onto this sheet. I am trying to use the FILTER function to get the buyer's name, address etc. and because the amount of orders changes every day, I use an open-ended range. For example: FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("link", "sheet!Q2:Q"), IMPORTRANGE("link", "sheet!A2:A") = D2:D). Column A on the other sheet and column D on this sheet are the order ID's, which I am using to get the buyer information.

The problem is that no matter what I do, I get an error like: "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: ____. column count: ____. Actual row count: _____, column count: ____." I don't know how to fix that because all my ranges are open-ended.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!